# How to increase searchability of answered question

Tags: discussion, tags, search

This has happened to me several times, my most recent example is not my best, but to find this:

[output to the same line overwriting previous output ? python (2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Took a few goes on google and then followed a couple of links to related questions on SO. In other cases while looking for something esoteric I've spent a long time searching. Is there anything that I, or another reader with little to no reputation can do to help make this question more findable for other searchers?

For example, I was looking for "printing dynamic variable python 3" or "print changing value"

This particular one wasn't too hard to find (see first line) but it is a general question from a newbie who knows how much duplicates are hated here.

Comment: If you think you can make a question more visible then you can suggest an edit. underneath the question is an edit link, if you can make the title or content clearer, then suggest an edit. With your reputation, any edits you make will have to be reviewed by other users before they are applied to the post.

Comment: The way the question was written matters a great deal, the more relevant keywords the better.  That is not an easy question to find back, the problem does not have anything to do with FTP and it has more code than text.  You'd have to be lucky and use "overwrite" in the search query.  Pretty remarkable that it then turns out well, although you might find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419389/17034).  That's okay, same question.